# R -plot 12 images per plot or save 12 images per image file in R

Tags: raster, r, stack

Here is R script and my question is
How can I plot 12 images per plot or save 12 images per image file because I have total 864 images.

```
RAD1998 <- raster(paste(getwd(), "/1998bil /1998ASC5min_ppt_spas1214_0001_19980202_0810_UTC.asc.bil", sep = ""))

list.ras <- mixedsort(list.files(paste(getwd(), "/1998bil/", sep = ""), full.names = T, pattern = ".asc.bil")) 
list.ras
png('RAD1998.png')
RAD1998.all <- stack(list.ras)
plot(RAD1998.all)
dev.off()
```

Comment: I would use `levelplot` from `rasterVis` package to plot `RAD1998.all`.

Comment: levelpot is a good suggestion, http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/. I am studying now. Thanks, Nahm

Comment: level plot is great but I have one problem if levelplot index is in static then it works but not in a loop. Do you have any suggestions? Here is a codes. Thanks, png(paste("1998",outlist[[1]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[1:4]])
dev.off()

png(paste("1998",outlist[[5]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[5:8]])
dev.off()

png(paste("1998",outlist[[9]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[9:12]])
dev.off()



for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(list.ras), by=4)){
      png(paste("1998_",outlist[[i]],".png",sep=""))
 levelplot(RAD1998.all[[i:i+3]])
 dev.off()

}

Comment: You need to stack your rasters first, then use levelplot, i.e `levelplot(RAD1998.all)`.

Comment: I already stacked it. RAD1998.all <- stack(list.ras)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose `rasterVis::levelplot`, the `layout` argument will help you. Details about this argument can be found in the help page of `lattice::xyplot:`

> ‘layout’ is a numeric vector of length 2 or 3 giving the number of columns, rows, and pages (optional) in a multipanel display.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster()
ll <- list()

for (i in 1:48) ll[[i]] <- init(r, runif)
s <- stack(ll)

trellis.device('png', file = 'myPic%02d.png')
levelplot(s, layout = c(3, 4))
dev.off()
```

Comment: It worked very well. I don't need a for loop. Very neat. Thanks,Nahm

Comment: I like this method. It works with even California map.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the number of plots per graphic device using the mfrow and mfcol arguments in par().

```
par(mfrow=c(3,4))
  for(i in 1:12) {plot(runif(100),runif(100)*0.05)}
```

Comment: I can see3 by 4 plots per plot page but somehow all of images are are showing linear dots. I don't know what to do

Comment: Not sure what you mean. My example is just an x,y plot. You do realize that png is not a multipage device? If you want plot numerious rasters I would recommend a pdf device. After setting a graphic device and par() settings, you will also need to create a loop to plot each raster. Something like: for(i in 1:nlayer(RAD1998.all)) {plot(RAD1998.all[[i]])}

Comment: I need time to figure out PDF. But I tried it with Tiff file and now I can save 864 GTiff files and I need to combine second suggestion and 1st suggestion. Good progress. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am getting there. Now I can see 3 by 4 images correctly in every single plot and I still generate 864 images files.

Comment: After I combined your suggestions and couple of other sources, then it works now and thanks a lot. Here is codes.                                             

for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(list.ras), by=4)){
      pdf(paste("myOut",i,".pdf",sep=""))
 par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 for(j in 1:4){
    plot(RAD1998.all[[i+j]])
 }
      dev.off()
}
dev.off()

Comment: Thanks for two sources also #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287364/for-loop-in-r-with-increments
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395410/how-to-print-r-graphics-to-multiple-pages-of-a-pdf-and-multiple-pdfs